# How filter second dropdown based on first dropdown value inside the kendogrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to filter second Dropdown based on first dropdown value inside the Kendogrid

```
enter code here
  @(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("windowFactorDefination").Iframe(true)
                                .Title("Rating Factor Definition")
                                .Draggable()
                                .Resizable()
                                .Modal(true)
                                .Visible(false)
                                .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
                                .Width(850)
                                .Events(e => e.Close("OnCloseFactorWindow"))
                                .Position(settings => settings.Top(30))
                                .Position(settings => settings.Left(100))
                                .Content(@<text>
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<WeezerSetup.Model.RatingGroup>()
                                .Name("FactorDefinationGrid")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.RatingFactorDefinitionID).Visible(false);
                                                                            columns.Bound(c => c.FactorDefinationDescription).Title("Factor Definition Description").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Rating Factor description" });
                                    columns.ForeignKey(b => b.FactorTypeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.FactorList).Width(120).Title("Factor Type").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Data type for Rating Factor" });
                                    columns.ForeignKey(c => c.TableID, (SelectList)ViewBag.TableList).Width(300).EditorTemplateName("TableTypeEditorDropDown").Title("SYS_Table").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "drpTableType" });
                                    columns.ForeignKey(c => c.FieldID, (SelectList)ViewBag.FieldList).Width(300).EditorTemplateName("FieldTypeEditorDropDown").Title("SYS_Table_Field").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "drpFieldType" });
                                    columns.ForeignKey(b => b.WildCard, (SelectList)ViewBag.WildCardList).Width(300).Title("Wild Card").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Used when any remaining values have the same results" });
                                    columns.Command(command =>
                                    {
                                        command.Edit().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnEdit", @style = "text-align:center;", data_toggle = "tooltip", data_placement = "top", title = "Edit" });
                                    }).HeaderTemplate("Action").Width(210);
                                    columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fe-delete", title = "DELETE" }); }).HeaderTemplate("Action").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { title = "Clicking the icon will Delete specific row" });
                                })
                                    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                                    .Sortable()
                                    .AutoBind(true)
                                    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
                                    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                    .Refresh(true)
                                    .PageSizes(true)
                                    .ButtonCount(5))
                                    .Filterable()
                                    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                                    .Events(events => { events.Edit("onEditGrdMyBenefitsGrid"); events.DataBound("onRowDataBoundGrdMyBenefitsGrid"); })

                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .PageSize(5)
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetRatingFactorDefination", "RateSetup"))
                                    .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.RatingFactorDefinitionID);
                                    })
                                    .Create(update => update.Action("AddFactorDefination", "RateSetup"))
                                    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateFactorDefination", "RateSetup"))
                                    .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("DeleteRatingFactorDefinition", "RateSetup").Data("DeleteRecord"))
                                    ))
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
                                 .For("#FactorDefinationGrid")
                                .Filter("th")
                                .Position(TooltipPosition.Top)
                                .Width(160)
                                .Events(events => events.Show("onShow"))
                                    )
                                </text>))}
```

So in the above code there are 2 columns Name TableID and FieldID both are dependent column showing as dropdown in the Kendo Grid UI.

Please give me solution to filter both dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a behavior like cascading drop downs. 
Refer to this [demo link](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist)

You need to do the following:-

1) Add cascade from property to editor template of FieldId

```
.CascadeFrom("TableId")
```

2) Add a function to your script file to return the selected table id

```
function filterFields() {
                return {
                    tableId: $("#TableId").val()
                };
            }
```

3) Add the script function in your read call

```
.DataSource(source => {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
                          .Data("filterFields");
                  })
.ServerFiltering(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will try to implement based on your solution. I hope this solution also will work with KendoGrid ==> DropDown.